# List of checked out files by others in Perforce

Tags: perforce

How can I get a list of all checked out files by user abc in Perforce?

Also, how can I get a list of all checked out files by me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Same answer for both:

```
p4 opened -u <username>
```