# Determine perforce users that have a file checked out

Tags: perforce

I have read these questions:

- [List of checked out files by others in Perforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828144/list-of-checked-out-files-by-others-in-perforce)
- [Perforce File Locked By Departed User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875303/perforce-file-locked-by-departed-user)

However these both deal with finding all the checked out files for a user. This is very useful, but I need to go the other way; what I really want to do is see **who has checked out a particular file**. Having read [the P4 docs](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/p4_opened.html), I see no way to do this.

Is there a way in P4 I can check who all has checked out a particular file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Stupid me found it as soon as I asked.

With P4 in Windows, navigate to the file (it's easy with Ctrl + Shift + S in the P4 Workspace view). Right-click it -> Perforce -> Properties. Look under the "Checked Out By" tab. You can also mouse-over the file icon to invoke a tooltip which will reveal this.

Turns out the same docs I linked to also show how to do it with the command line (`p4 opened -a filename`), even if not explicitly offered. The docs say

> To determine whether or not another user already has a particular file opened, use p4 opened -a file.

This is a bit of a headscratcher. While you can use this to check *if* a user has checked out a file, it more specifically lists the users and workspaces in which this file is checked out.

Comment: In p4v (2017.2) on Ubuntu Ctrl + Shift + S in the P4 Workspace view does not work and there is no option for "Perforce" in the right-click menu.  Mousing over the file does work.